# Why Is The index A Class From A Rendered List Using map Function In React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I created a simple list app using react hooks with useReducer. 
The list renders with no problem when an item is added but the problem arises when a button is clicked to remove an item. Nothing happens.
When I console.log the index passed from the map function index is a class.
Why is this happening?

See code below on StackBlitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jxgqwc

I expect the index to be the index of an item in the listItems array, not a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the two main pieces of code involved:

```
  const handleItemDelete = (index) => {
    console.log(index) //<==== why is index is a class?
    dispatch({
      type: "DELETE_ITEM",
      itemId: index,
    });
  };
```

```
      <ul>
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index.toString()}>
            {item}{" "}
            <button
              onClick={handleItemDelete}
            >
              X
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
```

When the `onClick` event occurs, the thing passed to it will be the `event` object. If you want the index, then you need something like: `onClick={()=>handleItemDelete(index)}`.

Here's a modified version of your code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tptvnx?file=index.js

Answer (score 4):

It is a React Click-Event.

Change your click-event on the Button to this:
`onClick={() => handleItemDelete(index)}`

And then it works. 
The default parameter for an onClick EventHandler is a click event which the console showed as a Class.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you not pass the index to handleItemDelete
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-siywgo?file=index.js